# Prove $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {X_n}$ is convergent with probability $1$ $\iff$ $P({|X_1|} =0)=1$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ be iid.

Goal: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {X_n}$ is convergent with probability $1$ $\iff$ $P({|X_1|} =0)=1$.

I already proved one direction: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {X_n}$ is convergent with probability $1\,\Longrightarrow\,P({|X_1|} =0)=1$ using Kolmogorov's three-series theorem.

To prove another implication i tried Kolmogorov's three-series theorem too, but i stuck in series of variance and expected value. Is this valid method?

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct statement is:

$\sum  X_n$ is **convergent** with probability $1$ iff $P(|X_1|=0)=1$.

If the series converges with probability $1$ then $X_n \to 0$ with probabiltiy $1$ and hence $X_n \to 0$ in probability. Thus $P(|X_n| >\epsilon)  \to 0$. This means $P(|X_1| >\epsilon) = 0$ for every $\epsilon >0$. Can you finish?

Converse is obvious.

Comment: Yes, i did that  same way as you. But I don't understand  why converse is obvious. Can you give me some hints?

Comment: @Pear If $X_1=0$ w.p. $1$ then $X_n=0$ w.p. $1$ for every $n$. How can you have any doubt about convergence of the series $0+0+0+...$?  Perhaps, you are getting confused becasue you have still not changed divergent to convergent in the body of the question.

Comment: Yes!  I didn't notice that. Now everything is clear. Thank you!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: I am not sure it is that simple for the converge. $X_i(\omega)$ may not all be $0$ for an arbitrary sample $\omega$. The probability is measured for the infinite sum not an individual $X_i$. There needs more detailed argument.

Comment: @Hans If you are talking about the concverse part, $P(X_1=0)=1$ implies that $P(X_n=0)=1$ for each $n$ and this implies that $P(X_n=0 \forall n)=1$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: What you say is true. However, it does not suffice to prove the result regarding the summation. You need to prove $\exists x(\omega)\in R \ni P\big(\omega\big|\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_i(\omega) = x(\omega) \big)=1$. In short how do you "move" $P$ from $P(X_i)$ within the summation $\sum$ to outside of the summation?

Comment: @Hans $x(\omega)=0$ for all $\omega$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: I know you are claiming that, but you have not proved it.

Comment: @Hans If each $X_i$ is $0$ with probability $1$, then the sum is also $0$ with probability $1$, because the probability of any individual term in the sum being nonzero, is zero. What’s the extra detail you imagine to be missing?

Comment: @RiversMcForge Right comment. I will not respond to queries by Hans from now on. I think he even downvoted this clear answer.

Comment: @RiversMcForge and Kavi Rama Murthy: Maybe I am being a stickler. I am sorry if I have irritated Kavi Rama Murthy. The key to the converse is that the set $S$ of $\sum X_n\ne 0$ is covered by the countable union of measure zero set which is of measure zero, and thus the measure of $S$ is zero. Then the conclusion follows. Maybe you think this is too trivial to state. But then there is nothing at all to say for this problem since this statement is as sophisticated as or as trivial as the answer above for the opposite direct statement. So I think one should either state both or state neither.

Comment: @Hans That's just a more technical and complicated-sounding rephrasing of what I said in my comment. Whether or not it's "trivial", I agree with Kavi that it's obvious.

Comment: @RiversMcForge: I am saying it is as obvious, or trivial, whichever the word you would like to pick, as the answer given above for the reverse direction. So they should be treated on the equal footing.